# Prove that $P\in Ass_{R}{M/(f_{1},f_{2},..,f_{s})M}$.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a finite generated Cohen-Macaulay $(R,\mathfrak{m})$-module and $(f_{1},f_{2},..,f_{s})$ are $M$-regular in $P$ with $P\in Supp_{R}{M}$. Take $Q\in Supp_{R}{M}$ such that $P\subset Q$. Prove that $PR_{Q}\in Ass_{R_{Q}}(M/(f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{s}M))_{Q}$.

Here is my draft:
$PR_{Q}\in Ass_{R_{Q}}(M/(f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{s}M))_{Q}=Spec(R_{Q})\cap Ass_{R}(M/(f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{s}M)$ or $P\in Ass_{R}(M/(f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{s})M)$.
However, it is probably wrong. Please help me check this question.

Comment: That $s$ should be $\dim M$, otherwise the claim is still wrong for $s=0$.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I think that could be wrong statement.